# F# Analysis of Option Statement

Tags: recursion, f#

I have extracted the following line from a function that's starts like so (textbook example incomplete):

```
    let rec unify (exp1:exp) (exp2:exp) (k:(subst -> subst)) (sub:subst) =
            match checkmap exp1 sub,checkmap exp2 sub with                                          
                | Var a,Var b when a = b -> k sub                                                   
                | Var a,Var b -> k (safeInput<|||((safeInput<|||(sub,a,Var(b))),b,Var(a)))
```

Line:

```
    Var a,Var b -> k (safeInput<|||((safeInput<|||(sub,a,Var(b))),b,Var(a)))
```

The safeInput reference 'safely' inputs a type into a Map structure... I am just wondering what the operators here are actually doing? Also, if there is a more intuitive way to structure the above line?

Comment: I think for a more complete answer you need to post more of the code.  _uniify_ is marked as recursive but as the code stands it doesn't need to be--so it looks like there's code missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you type

```
(<|||);;
```

into F# Interactive, you get its signature:

```
val it : (('a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'd) -> 'a * 'b * 'c -> 'd) = <fun:it@1>
```

Its definition is something like

```
let inline (<|||) f (a, b, c) = f a b c
```

so the last expression can be rewritten to

```
k (safeInput (safeInput sub a (Var b)) b (Var a))
```

To improve the function, you can also:

- Create let bindings to hold immediate values
- Reuse `exp1` and `exp2` instead creating the same values

e.g.

```
let rec unify (exp1 : exp) (exp2 : exp) (k : subst -> subst) (sub : subst) =
    match checkmap exp1 sub,checkmap exp2 sub with
    | Var a, Var b when a = b -> k sub
    | Var a, Var b -> 
        let sub' = safeInput sub a exp2
        k (safeInput sub' b exp1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<|||` operator simply passes the arguments on the right (provided as a tuple) to the function on the left, so the line means the same as:

```
k (safeInput (safeInput sub a (Var b)) b (Var a))
```

Or, if you want to split the line into two to make it more readable:

```
let sub' = safeInput sub a (Var b)
k (safeInput sub' b (Var a))
```

I don't know the book that uses this, but I suppose the idea is to add mapping from variable 'a' to variable 'b' and another mapping back from variable 'b' to variable 'a'.